# Javascript function does not start and I'm not sure how to fix?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm writing my first Javascript function where user can type in text with Prompt, user says which words in the text they would like to replace with prompt and eventually the new text gets shown in html.

The function doesn't start though (e.g. there's not even a prompt popping up. I'm sure it's a huge beginner mistake but I just cant figure it out. Hope someone can help me out here!

```js
 function wordReplacer() {
   function originalTextPrompt() {
       var originalText = prompt("Write your text here")
    function wordToBeReplacedPrompt() {
        var wordToBeReplaced = prompt("Type the word to be replaced")
        function newWordPrompt() {
            var newWord = prompt("With what word would you like the previous word to be replaced?") 
            var txt = originalText;
            txt = txt.replace (wordToBeReplaced, newWord);
            document.getElementById('wordreplacerid').innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
   
<button type="button" onclick="wordReplacer()">
Click here to convert text
</button>
<p id="wordreplacerid"></p>
```

I expected a prompt to start, but it seems like the function doesn't run.

Comment: Formatting your code would certainly help spot obvious syntax errors, i.e. your missing closing curly braces.

Comment: I tried to format your code, I supposed they were nested functions, feel free to revert if it's wrong

Comment: Yes, nested functions that are not being closed and not being called. I think there is more code to be pasted.

Comment: Agree, there are 3 inner functions that you maybe don't need, check that please and tell us more

Comment: What's the problem with leaving out semicoli? The code may be ambigious. Since there are entire chapters in books on the topic of *automatic semicolon insertation (how the engine decides where to insert a semocolon)* I'd not take the chance and hope that the engine gets my intentions and always puts them in at the right place. A bit verbose, I know. But untill **you** understand where a missing semicolon will create an ambguity that leads to an error x00 lines down and **you'll** have to find that, you should not leave out semicoli.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following code. You dont need so many functions for achieve your desired behavior

```
function wordReplacer() {
    var originalText = prompt("Write your text here")

    var wordToBeReplaced = prompt("Type the word to be replaced")


    var newWord = prompt("With what word would you like the previous word to be replaced ? ")   
    var txt = originalText; 
    txt = txt.replace(wordToBeReplaced, newWord); 
    document.getElementById('wordreplacerid').innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function wordReplacer() {
  function originalTextPrompt() {
    var originalText = prompt("Write your text here")
    function wordToBeReplacedPrompt() {
      var wordToBeReplaced = prompt("Type the word to be replaced")
      function newWordPrompt() {
        var newWord = prompt("With what word would you like the previous word to be replaced?") 
        var txt = originalText;
        txt = txt.replace (wordToBeReplaced, newWord);
        document.getElementById('wordreplacerid').innerHTML = txt;
      }
    }
  }
} //Adding theses
```

I think you can spend some time on a better tooling.
Take 5 min to check theses:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/
- https://prettier.io/
- https://quokkajs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You declare two sub-functions but do not close the braces or call them.
Better:

```js
 function wordReplacer() {
      var originalText = prompt("Write your text here");
      var wordToBeReplaced = prompt("Type the word to be replaced");
      var newWord = prompt("With what word would you like the previous word to be replaced?");
      var txt = originalText;
      txt = txt.replace (wordToBeReplaced, newWord);
      document.getElementById('wordreplacerid').innerHTML = txt;
    }
```

```html
  
    <button type="button" onclick="wordReplacer()">
 Click here to convert text
    </button>
    <p id="wordreplacerid"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only calling `wordReplacer()` but inside this function, there is a hierarchy of functions.

Inside `wordReplacer()` there is `originalTextPrompt()` which is not called that's why you are not getting any output.

You are performing too many hierarchy of functions which is not needed.

Try below code.

```
function wordReplacer() {
    var originalText = prompt("Write your text here");
    var wordToBeReplaced = prompt("Type the word to be replaced");
    var newWord = prompt("With what word would you like the previous word to be replaced ? ");
    var txt = originalText; 
    txt = txt.replace(wordToBeReplaced, newWord); 
    document.getElementById('wordreplacerid').innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a second answer showing how to use functions.

```js
 function wordReplacer() {
      function originalTextPrompt() {
          return prompt("Write your text here");
      }
      function wordToBeReplacedPrompt() {
          return prompt("Type the word to be replaced");
      }
      function newWordPrompt() {
          return prompt("With what word would you like the previous word to be replaced?");
      }
      var originalText = originalTextPrompt();
      var wordToBeReplaced = wordToBeReplacedPrompt();
      var newWord = newWordPrompt();
      
      var txt = originalText;
      txt = txt.replace (wordToBeReplaced, newWord);
      document.getElementById('wordreplacerid').innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
  
    <button type="button" onclick="wordReplacer()">
 Click here to convert text
    </button>
    <p id="wordreplacerid"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function wordReplacer() {
  function originalTextPrompt() {
    var originalText = prompt("Write your text here");
    function wordToBeReplacedPrompt() {
      var wordToBeReplaced = prompt("Type the word to be replaced");
      function newWordPrompt() {
        var newWord = prompt(
          "With what word would you like the previous word to be replaced?"
        );
        var txt = originalText;
        txt = txt.replace(wordToBeReplaced, newWord);
        document.getElementById("wordreplacerid").innerHTML = txt;
      }
    }
  }
}
```